# Where each of them used?

Tags: sql, hana, sap-erp

When I am studying about SAP HANA I come across various SQL terms

- Open SQL
- Native SQL
- SQL script

Can somebody explain which one we use in HANA studio while creating CDS view or scripted calculation view  and which SQL we use in our normal ECC program

I am little confused.

Comment: Open SQL is what we used to use before HANA is introduced. I thought SQLScript was the name for SQL developed for HANA database (just like Transact-SQL for SQL Server, PL/SQL for Oracle, etc) but I'm not sure

Answer (score 1):

We have to start from a bit further

### ABAP

Most SAP applications are written in their own programming language, ABAP (some is in java)

### Open SQL

When you want to talk to your database in your ABAP program, you have to write SQL. As R3 from SAP works with most relational databases, a common set of features had to be used, with some SAP specific extensions which are translated by the ABAP kernel to be understood by the actual DB. This portable language is called Open SQL.
HAVING and UNION were not allowed for example before 2017, but easy insturctions are added to define where the result is stored.

### Native SQL

If you develop for only one database, you can use its *native* instructions. These can bring additional features or speed, at the cost of transportability.

### HANA

For decades SAP did not sell databases, you had to buy one for your ERP system from a third party. A few yeards back SAP started to create its own DB, called **HANA**.
When you call it from ABAP, you can use **Open SQL**. If you create a CDS view in HANA Studio, you write **Native SQL**.

### SQLscript

If you want to write stored procedures, you have to use SQLscript, also developed by SAP. With it you have features completely foreign to SQL like loops.
It is just like Transact-SQL for SQL Server, PL/SQL for Oracle, etc - as  Eralper wrote